# fetch function in react just works when i clear the google chrome cache

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb

I have a really strange problem,

in my react app, there is 1 file that related to this problem ,

website not connecting to the backend api(node js )

but if u clear google chrome cache , it work just 1 time ! and u must again clear cashe to fetch all posts from database

I searched in stackoverflow , this problem is really wired

no cors policy in google chrome console

please look this 2 file and see if there is infinity loop maybe ? or i do not know why thus happening

this is my postlist.js file that i fetch posts from mongodb into main page of website

```
import { nanoid } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import tw from 'twin.macro';
import Advertise from "../../pages/PostPage/components/Advertise";
import Placeholder from "../Placeholder";
import Post from "./components/Post";
import rehypeVideo from "rehype-video";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import LoadingSpinner from "../LoadingSpinner/LoadingSpinner";





// import AutoDarkMode from 'auto-dark-mode';
// const theme = null; // will apply the default one
// // some elemens may got corrupted so double rotate them 
// const doubleRotatedElements = ['img', 'video']; 
// new AutoDarkMode(theme, doubleRotatedElements);
  






// import ArticleSkeleton from './ArticleSkeleton';
const PostsList = ({ filteredPosts,filteredTag, toInvalidate, enableImages = true }) => {
  const advertise = async () => {
    window?.EventBus?.emit("reset-ads");
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    advertise();
  }, []);

  const [posts, setposts] = useState(null);
  const [loading, setisLoading] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchAgain = async () => {
      if (posts != null) {
        let skip = posts.length;
        // await fetch(`${process.env.BASE_URL}/posts?limit=4&skip=${skip}`)
        await fetch(`http://127.0.0.1:5000/posts?limit=6&skip=${skip}`)
          .then((res) => res.json())
          .then((result) => setposts([...posts, ...result]));
      }
    };

    const handleScroll = () => {
      const html = document.documentElement;
      const body = document.body;
      const windowheight =
        "innerHeight" in window ? window.innerHeight : html.offsetHeight;

      const docHeight = Math.max(
        body.scrollHeight,
        body.offsetHeight,
        html.clientHeight,
        html.scrollHeight,
        html.offsetHeight
      );

      const windowBottom = windowheight + window.pageYOffset;
      if (windowBottom >= docHeight) {
        console.log("we reached the bottom");
        fetchAgain();
      }
    };

    window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);

    return () => window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
  }, [posts]);




  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(async () => {
      // const res = await fetch(`${process.env.BASE_URL}/posts?limit=4`)
      const res = await fetch("http://127.0.0.1:5000/posts?limit=1");
      
      const data = await res.json();

      setposts(data);
      console.log(data);
    }, 2000);
  }, []);



  return (
    <Wrapper>
      {
        posts?.length > 0 ? (
          posts.map((post, i) => (
            <>
              <>
                <Post
                filteredPosts={filteredPosts}
                  post={post}
                  isFirstPost={enableImages && i++}
                  filteredTag={filteredTag}
                  key={nanoid()}
                  toInvalidate={toInvalidate}
                />
                <Advertise />
              </>
            </>
          ))
        ) : (
          <>
            <LoadingSpinner />
          </>
        )
        // (

        //   <Placeholder />

        // )
      }
    </Wrapper>
  );
};

// const Wrapper = tw.div`w-full border border-pink-300`;
const Wrapper = tw.div`w-full`;

export default PostsList;
```

and this is another file that I think maybe problem is here

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import tw, { styled } from 'twin.macro';
import LoadingSpinner from '../../../common/LoadingSpinner';
// import PostsList from '../../../common/PostsList';
import { useGetPostsQuery } from '../../../core/features/posts/postsApiSlice';
import Postslistxx from '../../Tag/Postlistsxx';
import Posts1 from './Posts1';



import { nanoid } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
  import Post from '../../../common/PostsList/components/Post';
import Placeholder from '../../../common/Placeholder/Placeholder';

const PostsList = ({ posts, filteredTag, toInvalidate, enableImages = true }) => {
  return (
    <Wrapper>
      {posts?.length > 0 ? (
        posts.map((post, i) => (
          <Post
            post={post}
            isFirstPost={enableImages && i === 0}
            filteredTag={filteredTag}
            key={nanoid()}
            toInvalidate={toInvalidate}
          />
        ))
      ) : (
        <Placeholder />
      )}
    </Wrapper>
  );
};









const Posts = ({ value }) => {
  const { data: posts, isLoading } = useGetPostsQuery(null, {
    refetchOnMountOrArgChange: true,
  });
  const [filteredPosts, setFilteredPosts] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setFilteredPosts(posts?.filter(post => post.title.toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase())));
  }, [value, posts]);

  return isLoading ? (
    <LoadingSpinner />
  ) : (
    filteredPosts && <PostsList posts={filteredPosts} enableImages={false} />
  );
};

  const Wrapper = tw.div`bg-blue`;

export default Posts;
```

Answer (score 0):

First, there is two `PostsList` in the code you provide, I will assume the correct one is the first one.

You are setting `posts` twice :

- Once in the useEffect that is triggered only on mount (empty dependency array)
- Once in the `fetchAgain` function which is inside a useEffect that is triggered when `posts` change.

This does not seem good for what you are complaining for. Without telling us how the data should trigger a refetch I can not really help you, but there should be a use of `setPosts` somewhere to trigger the refetch (but that does not make any sense since it would trigger the useEffect and reset `posts`).

I can only advice you to clean and rethink your code from the beginning, retracing what it is doing so the probleme will appear to you without any doubt.

Comment: this was working fine , i do not know what i did , it is infinity scroll, because this 2 fetch, what is problem,canu explain a little more, why clearing cache in chrome make fetch works?

Comment: My bad sorry, I didnt notice your eventListener. Are you sure you are using the first `PostsList` (the one containing the eventListener and all the infinite scroll code) ? Because in your `Posts` component, you are using a `PostsList` but the import is commented, so it looks like you are using the one that does nothing.

Comment: exactly . i did that from purpose . because i thought i fix another issue (search function is not working after i add infinity scroll to website . but i removed the code from postlist and copy in post to make search function worked , and it worked , but when i use import it not work, then this issues occured , that fetch function in post list took so long to respond and even not responding , it seems it fetch all the records in database , but it only shows 8 of them and i do not know what i am doing ,

Comment: problem is here i fixx the search issue , but wonder why fetch function in post list not working and when i clear google chrome cache it worked ) i even asked another question and i am trying to fix can u look this question ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76140634/storing-data-domexception-failed-to-execute-setitem-on-storage-setting-the