# storing data DOMException: Failed to execute 'setItem' on 'Storage': Setting the value of 'persist:root' exceeded the quota

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I can not understand why this error in google chrome console

after i made some changes to code and not fetching api(backend)

it just fetch when i clear google chrome cache

i have 2 file related to this

please some one correct my code . why this error happen to me , cause i can not fetch the api backend

```
import { nanoid } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import tw from 'twin.macro';
import Advertise from "../../pages/PostPage/components/Advertise";
import Placeholder from "../Placeholder";
import Post from "./components/Post";
import rehypeVideo from "rehype-video";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import LoadingSpinner from "../LoadingSpinner/LoadingSpinner";





// import AutoDarkMode from 'auto-dark-mode';
// const theme = null; // will apply the default one
// // some elemens may got corrupted so double rotate them 
// const doubleRotatedElements = ['img', 'video']; 
// new AutoDarkMode(theme, doubleRotatedElements);
  






// import ArticleSkeleton from './ArticleSkeleton';
const PostsList = ({ filteredTag, toInvalidate, enableImages = true }) => {
  const advertise = async () => {
    window?.EventBus?.emit("reset-ads");
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    advertise();
  }, []);

  const [posts, setposts] = useState(null);
  const [loading, setisLoading] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchAgain = async () => {
      if (posts != null) {
        let skip = posts.length;
        await fetch(`${process.env.BASE_URL}/posts?limit=4&skip=${skip}`)
        // await fetch(`http://127.0.0.1:5000/posts?limit=6&skip=${skip}`)
          .then((res) => res.json())
          .then((result) => setposts([...posts, ...result]));
      }
    };

    const handleScroll = () => {
      const html = document.documentElement;
      const body = document.body;
      const windowheight =
        "innerHeight" in window ? window.innerHeight : html.offsetHeight;

      const docHeight = Math.max(
        body.scrollHeight,
        body.offsetHeight,
        html.clientHeight,
        html.scrollHeight,
        html.offsetHeight
      );

      const windowBottom = windowheight + window.pageYOffset;
      if (windowBottom >= docHeight) {
        console.log("we reached the bottom");
        fetchAgain();
      }
    };

    window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);

    return () => window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
  }, [posts]);




  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(async () => {
      const res = await fetch(`${process.env.BASE_URL}/posts?limit=8`)
      // const res = await fetch("http://127.0.0.1:5000/posts?limit=8");

      const data = await res.json();
      localStorage.clear();
      setposts(data);
      console.log(data);
    }, 9000);
  }, []);



  return (
    <Wrapper>
      {
        posts?.length > 0 ? (
          posts.map((post, i) => (
            <>
              <>
                <Post
                // filteredPosts={filteredPosts}
                  post={post}
                  isFirstPost={enableImages && i++}
                  filteredTag={filteredTag}
                  key={nanoid()}
                  toInvalidate={toInvalidate}
                />
                <Advertise />
              </>
            </>
          ))
        ) : (
          <>
            <LoadingSpinner />
          </>
        )
        // (

        //   <Placeholder />

        // )
      }
    </Wrapper>
  );
};

// const Wrapper = tw.div`w-full border border-pink-300`;
const Wrapper = tw.div`w-full`;

export default PostsList;
```

another file is

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import tw, { styled } from 'twin.macro';
import LoadingSpinner from '../../../common/LoadingSpinner';
// import PostsList from '../../../common/PostsList';
import { useGetPostsQuery } from '../../../core/features/posts/postsApiSlice';
// import Postslistxx from '../../Tag/Postlistsxx';
// import Posts1 from './Posts1';







import { nanoid } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
  import Post from '../../../common/PostsList/components/Post';
import Placeholder from '../../../common/Placeholder/Placeholder';

const PostsList = ({ posts, filteredTag, toInvalidate, enableImages = true }) => {
  return (
    <Wrapper>
      {posts?.length > 0 ? (
        posts.map((post, i) => (
          <Post
            post={post}
            isFirstPost={enableImages && i === 0}
            filteredTag={filteredTag}
            key={nanoid()}
            toInvalidate={toInvalidate}
          />
        ))
      ) : (
        <Placeholder />
      )}
    </Wrapper>
  );
};









const Posts = ({ value }) => {
  const { data: posts, isLoading } = useGetPostsQuery(null, {
    refetchOnMountOrArgChange: true,
  });
  const [filteredPosts, setFilteredPosts] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setFilteredPosts(posts?.filter(post => post.title.toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase())));
  }, [value, posts]);

  return isLoading ? (
    <LoadingSpinner />
  ) : (
    filteredPosts && <PostsList posts={filteredPosts} enableImages={false} />
  );
};

  const Wrapper = tw.div`bg-blue`;

export default Posts;
```

Please some one help me

Answer (score 1):

Each browser has a limit to the amount of data that can be stored in local storage and session storage. When this limit is exceeded, the 'setItem' method returns an error. To reduce the amount of data being stored in local storage, you can modify your code to fetch and display a portion of the data at a time by using pagination

```
import { nanoid } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import tw from 'twin.macro';
import Advertise from "../../pages/PostPage/components/Advertise";
import Placeholder from "../Placeholder";
import Post from "./components/Post";
import rehypeVideo from "rehype-video";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import LoadingSpinner from "../LoadingSpinner/LoadingSpinner";

const PostsList = ({ filteredTag, toInvalidate, enableImages = true }) => {
  const advertise = async () => {
    window?.EventBus?.emit("reset-ads");
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    advertise();
  }, []);

  const [posts, setPosts] = useState(null);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchAgain = async () => {
      if (posts != null) {
        let skip = posts.length;
        await fetch(`${process.env.BASE_URL}/posts?limit=4&skip=${skip}`)
        // await fetch(`http://127.0.0.1:5000/posts?limit=6&skip=${skip}`)
          .then((res) => res.json())
          .then((result) => setPosts([...posts, ...result]));
      }
    };

    const handleScroll = () => {
      const html = document.documentElement;
      const body = document.body;
      const windowheight =
        "innerHeight" in window ? window.innerHeight : html.offsetHeight;

      const docHeight = Math.max(
        body.scrollHeight,
        body.offsetHeight,
        html.clientHeight,
        html.scrollHeight,
        html.offsetHeight
      );

      const windowBottom = windowheight + window.pageYOffset;
      if (windowBottom >= docHeight) {
        console.log("we reached the bottom");
        fetchAgain();
      }
    };

    window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);

    return () => window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
  }, [posts]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const res = await fetch(`${process.env.BASE_URL}/posts?limit=8`);
        // const res = await fetch("http://127.0.0.1:5000/posts?limit=8");

        const data = await res.json();
        setPosts(data);
        console.log(data);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
      }
    };

    localStorage.clear();
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <Wrapper>
      {posts?.length > 0 ? (
        posts.map((post, i) => (
          <React.Fragment key={nanoid()}>
            <Post
              post={post}
              isFirstPost={enableImages && i === 0}
              filteredTag={filteredTag}
              toInvalidate={toInvalidate}
            />
            <Advertise />
          </React.Fragment>
        ))
      ) : (
        <LoadingSpinner />
      )}
    </Wrapper>
  );
```

In this implementation, the fetchPosts function fetches a maximum of 8 posts per page using the limit and page query parameters. The currentPage state variable keeps track of the current page number, and is incremented each time new posts are fetched.

The handleScroll function checks if the user has scrolled to the bottom of the page, and calls fetchPosts to fetch the next page of posts when this happens.

Note that in this implementation, the localStorage.clear() call has been removed, as it clears all data stored in local storage. If you need to clear specific data from local storage, you can use the localStorage.removeItem(key) method instead, where key is the name of the item you want to remove.

Comment: Hello , i do not know why this code u gave me cause not fetching at all

Comment: this is 2 pictures  of error https://i.postimg.cc/bdcp3Q7x/2222.png
https://i.postimg.cc/QCWjQ6yN/333.png

Comment: after i added your code into my code , new error shows , it said faild to fetch

Comment: now i think this code works well

Comment: thanks , but i am not using pages . it is infinity loading . how can i change this code and remove the pages from it ?

Comment: I put your code into try catch block without using current page because website is infinity loading  , just i add const fetchposts , it works faster than set timout, but the error is still there localstorage error

Comment: in my code, localstorage removed so i dont know why you gets this error ?

Comment: i added       localStorage.clear(); 5 times into my code , but speed a little changed but it took 20 second to fetch first 8 posts , just 8 post, this performance .do you think if u se axios instead of fetch it helps ?  can u hemp me with axios , i have to test i have to man

Comment: There's no need to use  localstorage , we re fetching data from api

Comment: If i remove that my application not fetching . ok i remove . but nothing changed . what i missing ? what is wrong with my application

Comment: okay i used the localstorage.clear() now, in my opinion there is no needed that but still didnt understand why it doesnt work for you